# Migrate Attachments as a Content Document in other org

Tags: attachment, contentdocument, data-migration

I am migrating the data from one org to another org. Let's assume Source Org as S (from where I need to migrate the data) and Destination Org as D (where I need to insert the Data). Now in org S, there are some Attachments which I need to insert/transfer into the org D. But in org D I need to insert it as a Content Document, not Attachment.

Any Idea for this?

Thanks

Nirav

Comment: It will be easier to migrate them as Attachments to destination, then run the Magic Mover app to convert them to Files after migration.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidCheng, but I can't do that as "Files uploaded to the Attachments related list on records are uploaded as Salesforce Files, not as attachments" this setting is enabled in org and I cannot disable it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to clarify what you are trying to do.  If you have enabled that setting, then you need to migrate Salesforce Files (content objects) and not old Attachments.  If that is the case, what is your specific question?